# Updating Sonar results using high latence network link

Tags: sonarqube

we're running tests and updating results to a Sonar server (using Mave by the way). Both machines, SONAR server and the test runner, are located in the same LAN.

Now some overseas teams wants to update their tests in our Sonar server through a high spped link 200 mseg round-trip link and the update into Sonar takes them more that 24 hours vs. 2 hours in our Local LAN.

Any ideas on how to cope with this issue ? 
Maybe some Sonar proxy (store and forward) ? Data movement between two Sonar instances ?

Thanks !

Comment: are you sure the update is taking so long, or is it the complete sonar job?

Comment: You're right what is taking so long is the complete Sonar job.

Comment: can you find out what takes so long, maybe you have to change some settings, so that e.g. findbugs works a bit faster.

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow you. The problem is that the same test run (mvn package sonar:sonar) takes 24 hours when the test and Sonar machine are connected across a 200 msec latency link vs. 2 hours when connected through a local LAN.

Clearly the problem here is the link latency, unless that I'm missing some setting that can speedup the process.

If that's not the case I was thinking adding a Sonar instance in the other team local LAN and use some data replication mechanism betwwen both Sonar instances.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with remote execution of the Batch process, which performs a huge amount of DB requests. We already have an open ticket for this topic: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-2119. Feel free to watch it and vote for it.
And to answer your question: there's currently no way to handle this issue if you want to do analyses on remote machines. The best option for the moment is to have only 1 build machine that is closed to the DB, and which can grab sources from remote locations.